# Overriding Symfony Controller Methods doesn't work properly

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, symfony-routing

I am trying to create a new controller function in the overridden controller class but it doesn't work as intended.

I have a common bundle where I use it for many clients. When sometimes when a client needs a specific function I creates an override for the common controller in the client bundle.

Here is my code for the common bundle controller.

```
class FrontController extends Controller
{
   // This is the controller in my common bundle

   /**
    * @Route("/foo/{id}", name="front_view")
    */
   public function viewAction(
       string $id,
       Request $request
   ){
       // My Controller code
   }
}
```

Here is my overridden controller code for client bundle.

```
class ClientFrontController extends FrontController
{
   // I have 2 controller methods in this class

  // First method overrides the FrontController's viewAction method
  // This works fine
  /**
    * @Route("/foo/{id}", name="front_view")
    */
   public function viewAction(
       string $id,
       Request $request
   ){
       // My Controller code
   }

  //Second method
  //This is the problem
  /**
    * @Route("/foo/bar", name="foo_bar")
    */
   public function fooBarAction(
       Request $request
   ){
       // My Controller code
   }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when I navigate to `/foo/bar` route, it goes to `/foo/{id}` the overridden method in `ClientFrontController`.

Why is this happening? How can I make both routes work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes order is relevant.

`/foo/bar` is included within `/foo/{id}`. When evaluating the request, `/foo/bar` matches `/foo/{id}` (with `id` being `bar`) and since it's declared/read earlier, `front_view` handles the request.

If you are on Symfony < 5.1, try moving the routes around (so that `foo_bar` comes earlier than `front_view`). Or even changing the routes so that there is no overlap.

If you are on Symfony 5.1+, you can now use `priority` on route annotations/attributes. Read [the announcement here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-route-annotations-priority), and the docs [here](https://symfony.com/index.php/doc/current/routing.html#priority-parameter).

```php
class ClientFrontController extends FrontController
{

   /**
    * @Route("/foo/{id}", name="front_view")
    */
   public function viewAction(string $id, Request $request)
   {
       // My Controller code
   }

   /**
    * @Route("/foo/bar", priority=10, name="foo_bar")
    */
   public function fooBarAction(Request $request)
   {
       // My Controller code
   }
}
```